# Anybody implemented EBS(External Blob Storage) in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010

Anybody implemented EBS(External Blob Storage) in sharepoint 2010 my content db is growing like crazy .If i have some "gotchas" that would be great

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using RBS doesn't mean you'll be using less disk space - if your content DBs are growing you're going to have to either just buy more storage or revise your data retention policies.

RBS is good if you have large binary data which will be streamed through to many users at once.

Answer (score 1):

Before implementing remote blob storage you need to determine what kind of data stuffs your Db's. RBS can degrade performance in some situations and you can't back it up using normal routines.

Comment: I am researching various options 
1) archiving solutions from third party (docvae, metalogix, storagepoint)
2) beef up my existing SQL hdd
3) create a different site collection so that i can move sqlserver for tht site collection on a different box
4) SAN -- most expensive option  
3)

Comment: What's the size of your content db's? You might consider splitting it up. Also what is growing, is it versioning of documents? Then consider removing old versions. RBS will not solve your storage problems as James says. You really need to look at it at a wider perspective first.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, properly implemented, RBS can significantly reduce storage requirements of your SharePoint content.  Compression, differential compression (...think versions), and de-duplication/single-instancing can all be leveraged.  Some 3rd party solutions provide this capability OOB and most medium and high-end SAN and NAS platforms provide some level of de-dupe or compression capabilities.

The comments about reducing performance are somewhat accurate as it relates to the RBS FILESTREAM provider, but are not as it relates to 3rd party providers.

Comment: De-duplication of uploaded binary content sounds actually pretty cool, if it works in practice. I'd like to see a good demo of this, as it'd be a very easy sell...

Comment: We have a single-instancing capability in our product and/or you can turn on compression (...we implement Zip64 OOB).

The single-instancing basically works off a MD5 hash and looks for existing copies of a document and does not store the dupe if it already exists in the blob store...this is all done asynchronously so it doesn't impact the end user.